# Javascript Form Math Rounding

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

So I am trying to make a simple form that takes a series of numbers (or lack of numbers) and adds them, does some division, and some multiplication.

That part works perfectly fine. The problem I am having is with Rounding. I have googled around a bit about this issue and found several people mentioning Math.round or Math.abs or Math.ceil and so forth. But none of these have worked for me (but I'm probably doing it wrong).

The first Total (sugar needed) works perfectly, the second and third totals do not work the way I need them to.

It needs to take the First Number (lets say "corn") and divide that number by 5, and then multiple it by 2 and again by 6, the result of 5 Corn would be 1 Sugar, 2 Fermenter, 6 Water. But any number other than 5 or 0 is not allowed. Meaning if I input something like this: Corn 8, the result needs to again be 1 Sugar, 2 Fermenter, 6 Water. But what I get is 1 Sugar, 3 Fermenter, 9 Water.

Similar problem with the totG and totB values.

```js
function findTotal() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
  var tot = 0 | 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('qtyG');
  var totG = 0 | 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      totG += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  var arr = document.getElementsByName('qtyB');
  var totB = 0 | 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      totB += parseInt(arr[i].value);

  }
  document.getElementById('total').value = Math.floor(tot / 5 + totG / 3 + totB);
  document.getElementById('total2').value = Math.floor(((tot / 5) * 2) + ((totG / 3) * 2) + (totB * 2));
  document.getElementById('total3').value = Math.floor(((tot / 5) * 6) + ((totG / 3) * 6) + (totB * 6));

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Corn
    </td>
    <td>
      <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Corn - Green Tier
    </td>
    <td>
      <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qtyG" id="qty2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <td>
    Corn - Blue Tier
  </td>
  <td>
    <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qtyB" id="qty3" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Potato
    </td>
    <td>
      <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty4" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Potato - Green Tier
    </td>
    <td>
      <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qtyG" id="qty5" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Potato - Blue Tier
    </td>
    <td>
      <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qtyB" id="qty6" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <td>
    Barley
  </td>
  <td>
    <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty7" />
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Barley - Green Tier
    </td>
    <td>
      <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qtyG" id="qty8" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Barley - Blue Tier
    </td>
    <td>
      <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qtyB" id="qty9" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Sweet Potato
    </td>
    <td>
      <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty10" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Sugar Needed
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="total" id="total" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Fermenter Needed
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="total" id="total2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Water Needed
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="total" id="total3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "But any number other than 5 or 0 is not allowed." - You mean for the quantities ?
Not sure if I understand. Try to be more precise. If any number other than 5 or 0 is not allowed for Corn, then I would simply check that number and replace it by a default value if it is not 0 or 5. What is wrong with that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should only be flooring the value / 5

```
document.getElementById('total').value = Math.floor(tot / 5) + Math.floor(totG / 3) + totB;
document.getElementById('total2').value = Math.floor(tot / 5) * 2 + (Math.floor(totG / 3) * 2) + (totB * 2);
document.getElementById('total3').value = Math.floor(tot / 5) * 6 + (Math.floor(totG / 3) * 6) + (totB * 6);
```

Comment: I need to math.floor the whole thing eventually because I get decimals with this new code.

Comment: Wrap it all in another Math.floor.  If this isn't what you're looking for, you will probably need more explanation in your question.

Comment: document.getElementById('total').value = Math.floor(tot / 5) + Math.floor(totG / 3) + totB;        this appears to be working

Comment: Either way should work.  Updated answer though based off your last comment